Hyperlink values within an IF EMPTY Ampscript statement
all. This is an Ampscript/SFMC inquiry below.
I am trying to solve for adding a hyperlink to an IF EMPTY statement and have it render outside. You can see the bold start a chapter identified below is where I am stuck.
I want to link to "...start a chapter" within the @ChapterName IF EMPTY statement and link it to the @ChapterLink link.
Has something like this been done before? Rendering a hyperlink from an IF EMPTY value?
%%[

/* Define and set variables for Chapter subscribers */

VAR @SubscriberKey 
SET @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey")

/*Lookup Contact Chapter Info*/

VAR @ChapterName
SET @ChapterName = Lookup("Membership_Welcome_DE","Name","SubscriberKey",@SubscriberKey)

VAR @ChapterLink
SET @ChapterLink = AttributeValue("ChapterLink")

SET @ChapterLink = "https://www.google.com/"

IF EMPTY(@ChapterName) THEN
SET @ChapterName = "If there is no chapter near you, **start a chapter**."

ENDIF

]%%

%%=v(@ChapterName)=%%<br>



Try this
Concat("If there is no chapter near you, start a chapter.")

%%[
/* Define and set variables for Chapter subscribers */
VAR @SubscriberKey, @ChapterName, @ChapterLink

SET @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey")

/* Lookup Contact Chapter Info */
SET @ChapterName = Lookup("Membership_Welcome_DE", "Name", "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)

/* Set ChapterLink */
SET @ChapterLink = AttributeValue("ChapterLink")

/* If ChapterLink is empty, set a default value */
IF EMPTY(@ChapterLink) THEN
    SET @ChapterLink = "https://www.google.com/"
ENDIF

/* If ChapterName is empty, set a default message with a hyperlink */
IF EMPTY(@ChapterName) THEN
    SET @ChapterName = Concat("If there is no chapter near you, <a href='", @ChapterLink, "'>start a chapter</a>.")
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@ChapterName)=%%<br>


Hello @Viswanath Josyula. CONCAT function worked! You are so helpful. Thank you.

@Bulldogstall Mark the answer it will be helpful for others.

I marked it as helpful. Thanks again.
